# Not Able to fetch Information of Login user From Google+ in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I m Using Google+ singing In in my app. when i clicked on Google Button onConnect() Method is called but from OnConnect() Method i m retrieving some information  from Google. but   "Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)" method is returning null value.  please help me

```
// Google API Services CallBack Method
        private boolean mSignInClicked;
        private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

        private void loginWithGoogle() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                Log.i("personName", personName);

                Image personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
                String photoUrl = personPhoto.getUrl();
                Log.i("photoUrl", photoUrl);

                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                Log.i("personGooglePlusProfile", personGooglePlusProfile);

                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                Log.i("email", email);

                boolean hasBirthday = currentPerson.hasBirthday();
                Log.i("hasBirthday", "" + hasBirthday);

                String birthday = currentPerson.getBirthday();
                Log.i("birthday", "" + birthday);

                boolean hasAbout = currentPerson.hasAboutMe();
                Log.i("hasAbout", "" + hasAbout);

                String about = currentPerson.getAboutMe();
                Log.i("about", "" + about);

                String Id = currentPerson.getId();
                Log.i("Id", Id);

                int gender = currentPerson.getGender();
                Log.i("gender", "" + gender);

                boolean hasLocation = currentPerson.hasCurrentLocation();
                Log.i("hasLocation", "" + hasLocation);

                String location = currentPerson.getCurrentLocation();
                Log.i("location", "" + location);

                AgeRange agerange = currentPerson.getAgeRange();
                if (agerange != null)
                    Log.i("agerange", "" + agerange.toString());

                Name name = currentPerson.getName();
                Log.i("getFamilyName", name.getFamilyName());

                btnGoogle = true;

                new ApiCall().execute(url);

                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("personName", "getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) is null");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            if (!mIntentInProgress) {
                mConnectionResult = result;
                if (mSignInClicked) {
                    // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                    // resolve
                    // all
                    // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
            }
        }

        public void resolveSignInError() {
            if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    mIntentInProgress = true;
                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    // The intent was canceled before it was sent. Return to the
                    // default
                    // state and attempt to connect to get an updated
                    // ConnectionResult.
                    mIntentInProgress = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you added `Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);`?

Comment: where? in onConnect() Method?

Comment: Yes in `OnConnected`

Comment: please can u give me the  full onConnect() method thanks in advance

Comment: whether you can get date of birth from google plus?

Comment: Hello! Which library do you use to get "Plus" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this line:  *Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);* in `onConnected`

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    /* This Line is the key */
    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);

    // After that  fetch data 
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            Log.i("personName", personName);
            ......
    }
}
```

Reference : [Retrieve the list of visible people in the user's circles](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people)

Hope it will help you ツ

Comment: no, i have added this " Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);" in onConnect() method. and i have implement its interface. but it is not working from me

Comment: Still are you getting NULL only ??

Comment: [have you followed all steps correclty ???](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) Make sure

Comment: i have used the link u provide and in the onResult() method "peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode()" is giving me 7

Comment: try [this](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/project/2013/271/g1327105/android-studio/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/wallet/src/com/google/android/gms/samples/wallet/LoginFragment.java) OR [this](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/plus/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java)

Comment: can sh1 id create the problem? because I think sh1 id is different which is register with google console

Comment: the key generated with sh1 and project name can be used in your project

Comment: but now i have changed it but still it is not working :(

Comment: can you tell me the reason in it. but still Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) return null

Comment: peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode()== 7 what does it means?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, this is most likely to be the reason. The issue lies in the certificate.

1) Did you use the correct SHA1 signature to generate the json config file and the right package name?

2) Did you sign the application using the same certificate?

2a) Remember regardless of build variant, Android Studio will always sign your application. If you did not specify one, the default development will be used. So unless you have provided the dev certificate signature to generate the config, it is likely to be a mismatch. Hence the null.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, I included the debug SHA1 key as well as the release SHA1 key and I was able to get the results back. Depending on how you are testing the app, in "Google Developer Console" try creating a new client key with the debug SHA1 and try again (So you will have 2 client keys on your api console, one for release and one for debug).